# @BeforeAll does not execute

Tags: java, cucumber, junit5

Recently, I migrated cucumber info.cukes to io.cucumber and Junit 4 to Junit 5 because the executions did not work with my java version.

my base page

```
public class BasePage {

    public static RemoteWebDriver driver;

    @BeforeAll
    public static void initWebDriver() {
        System.out.println("i will init Driver");
       initDriver()
   }
}
```

my Pom

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
        <version>5.8.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>5.8.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>5.8.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>7.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>7.1.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: And how does your test look like?

Comment: I think you should use a @RunWith....  annotation above the class name.  Something like: @RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class) public class BasePage .....

Comment: My Test:
'''
import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
     features = {"src/test/resources/features"}
        ,glue = ""
  ,tags = "@Test"
)'''

Comment: i tried add annotation: @RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class) public class BasePage  but  cannot resolve JUnitPlatform.class

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to run any Cucumber scenario at all you probebly are using the wrong import for the `@BeforeAll` annotation. Right ones are `io.cucumber.java.BeforeAll` and `io.cucumber.java.AfterAll`.

https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/java#hooks

```java
package io.cucumber.example;

import io.cucumber.java.AfterAll;
import io.cucumber.java.BeforeAll;

public class StepDefinitions {

    @BeforeAll
    public static void beforeAll() {
        // Runs before all scenarios
    }

    @AfterAll
    public static void afterAll() {
        // Runs after all scenarios
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not able run any tests at all, and you want to use only JUnit 5, and you do not want to use JUnit Vintage with Cucumber JUnit then you can use the [`cucumber-junit-platform-engine`](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/junit-platform-engine).

To do that you need these dependencies at minimum:

```xml
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-bom</artifactId>
                <version>5.8.2</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
                <artifactId>cucumber-bom</artifactId>
                <version>7.1.0</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit-platform-engine</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-suite</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

Note: you can use the `dependencyManagement` to only declare the version for Cucumber and JUnit once.

Then you can configure the runner class using the JUnit 5 Suite annotation.

```java
package io.cucumber.skeleton;

import org.junit.platform.suite.api.ConfigurationParameter;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.IncludeEngines;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.SelectClasspathResource;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.Suite;

import static io.cucumber.junit.platform.engine.Constants.PLUGIN_PROPERTY_NAME;

@Suite
@IncludeEngines("cucumber")
@SelectClasspathResource("io/cucumber/skeleton")
@ConfigurationParameter(key = PLUGIN_PROPERTY_NAME, value = "pretty")
public class RunCucumberTest {
}
```

For a minimum working example see: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-java-skeleton